# How to remove line breaks from Script Output in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

In Oracle SQL Developer Version 4.1.3.20.78, there are two or three line breaks after each line in the Script Output; here’s what I mean:

[image: Script Output with too many line breaks]

In the previous version I used (I don’t remember the version number now, but it was 4.x), there was only one line break. How do I change the line breaks back to the previous setting to have more compact Script Output?

Comment: I'm not sure this is intentional, partly because it seems to be inconsistent - sometimes one blank line, sometimes more than one, and it can change in repeated running of the same script. You might be better off asking about this on [the SQL Developer forum](https://forums.oracle.com/community/developer/english/development_tools/application_development_in_pl_sql/sql_developer_(not_for_general_sql_plsql_questions)).

Comment: @Alex Poole, on the contrary, it is perfectly consistent when I run it. No matter what script I run, it is the same line spacing.

Comment: Fair enough, but I get an inconsistent mix, on Windows and Mac. If there isn't a workaround - and I can't see any settings that affect script output, other than SQL\*Plus `set` commands that don't change this - you should still probably raise it on that forum, where the devs hang out.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer; I've posted the question there now: https://community.oracle.com/message/13618386. If they provide a good answer, I'll come back and answer the question here.